# How do I remove escape sequences (ESC[0;33m) from hg's output?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying out Mercurial. When I run `hg log` in the terminal, I see this output, paged through a pager, probably `less`:

```
ESC[0;33mchangeset:   1:82e55d328c8cESC[0m
tag:         tip
user:        mpm@selenic.com
date:        Fri Aug 26 01:21:28 2005 -0700
summary:     Create a makefile

ESC[0;33mchangeset:   0:0a04b987be5aESC[0m
user:        mpm@selenic.com
date:        Fri Aug 26 01:20:50 2005 -0700
summary:     Create a standard "hello, world" program
```

How do I configure Mercurial so that I don't see escape and control sequences like `ESC[0;33m` and `ESC[0m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sequences are meant to enable colour output in the terminal. You can disable colour by adding `--color=never`, like this:

```
hg log --color=never
```

Even better, you can change the pager to enable recognising these colour sequences. For example, you can use `less -R` on systems that have `less`. Modify `~/.config/hg/hgrc` or `~/.hgrc` to include this section:

```
[pager]
pager = less -R
```